# Sum of two random variables following K0 (modified 2nd kind Bessel) distributions

Tags: bessel-potential, pr.probability

If X and Y follow independently a density distribution represented by the function $\tfrac{1}{\pi} K_0\left(\tfrac{|x|}{a^2}\right)$ (a modified Bessel function of the second kind), then the sum $Z = X + Y$
seems to follow  a Laplace double exponential distribution, which for reminder is
$L(z) = \tfrac{1}{2a^2} \exp\left(-\tfrac{|z|}{a^2}\right)$.

Now, where I can find any demonstration of that property ?

Comment: Hello I am studying the same problem, practicing in MGF. In the MGF of the modified Bessel function of second kind I come up with the factor of arccos(t) in the numerator which I cannot see in your answers. Is it something that I am missing??

Answer (score 3):

This an easy exercise using moment generating functions. By scaling we can assume WLOG that $a = 1$. Then the MGF of the modified Bessel distribution is
$$ E[e^{tX}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}, $$
and hence the MGF of the sum of two independent such variables is $\frac{1}{1 - t^2}$, which is the MGF of the Laplace distribution.

Comment: My godness, I am so stupid... sorry and thanks to refresh my mind.
JE